# How to change content of an attribute in mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql

Now, I am doing a project. I am developing a web based information system. This project already has a database in Microsoft Access. I have to migrate the data to a mySQL database. But, there is a problem. The ID of the entities is a mess. I want to fix it and make some new ID for all the entities. I would use PHP to change ID in mySQL, but I don't know how. Maybe somebody can help me? As an example, I have "tbldocument" entity. The attributes of tbldocument are docID, docTitle, docType, and date. I want to change the content of docID. The existing condition is the docID has a different style. The ID consists of 4 characters and another consists of 11 characters. I want to make all of the IDs to be 11 characters, unique, and auto increment.

Maybe someone know how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: You will want an unsigned + zero-fill + auto-increment INT(11)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you have to connect to the database before you can change it.  You do that with the following:  `$mydb = mysqli_connect('yourHost', 'yourUserName', 'yourPassword', 'yourDatabase');`

After connecting to your database in PHP, you can use `mysqlyi_query($mydb, 'ALTER table tbldocument alter docID int(11) not null auto_increment')`

You can do that for every attribute that you want to change, and in fact any SQL you want to run from PHP, provided you have the correct permission.  Bear in mind that if you run any SQL with a result set, you will want to hold the result in a variable, so `$result = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM tblDocument')`

For more information, PHP has great documentation on databases [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)